# In Python, how to see if the property of the object returned from MongoDB exists on that object?

Tags: python, mongodb, exists

I return object from the MongoDB database, using python. I want to see now if the property revokedTokens exists. This is my code:

```
usersCollection = db["users"]
searchQuery = { "username": username }
user = usersCollection.find_one(searchQuery)

print("user is:")
print(user)

if hasattr(user, "revokedTokens"):
    print("appending")
    user["revokedTokens"].append("another")
    #user["revokedTokens"].append(jwt)
else:
    print("adding first element")
    user["revokedTokens"] = ["first"]
    #user["revokedTokens"] = [jwt]
```

but I always end up in the wrong print ( `print("adding first element")` ) , so I don't know how to check this. Thanks everyone for correcting me, I am a python newbie!

Comment: `if "revokedTokens" in user:`?

Comment: `user` will be a `dict` object. A `dict` object will never have any of those attributes (it has *others*, of course, e.g. the various dict methods). You want to check if the `dict` *contains* those keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[find_one](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#getting-a-single-document-with-find-one) returns a [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) so what you need to ask is `if "revokedTokens" in user` or `if user.get('revokedTokens') is not None`

Comment: Better to not use `if user.get(...)` because some values could be interpreted as false, see [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).

Comment: @OlvinRoght see latest code please.

Comment: `None` can also be a value retrieved from json `json.loads("null")` First option you provided is a proper way.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, it is probably better practice to use the `$exists` MongoDB [operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/).

To make your code work (if you don't want to use the MongoDB query way), you should replace:

`if hasattr(user, "revokedTokens"):`

with

`if "revokedTokens" in user:`

This is because the query returns a `dict` object, and not a structured class